# How to manage multiple observable in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

I have a angualr 7 application, and totally 20 sensor data. I want to receive data every 5 seconds using observable for selected sensor id. For example;

```
var sensorId = ""; // dynamically selected from the web UI
var sensorData$ = interval(5000).pipe()
sensorData$.subscribe() // etc..
```

I'll select  multiple sensor, and start to get data with subscribe using interval. How can I keep these observables? How can I manage it?

Also, I can add any sensor at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Subject and mergeMap.

As for explanation, you will have 1 Subject where you will emit new sensorIds when user selects one from the UI. Then you need to subscribe to that exact Subject and with the help of mergeMap you will have all of the sensor values in your subscribe method.

Lets look at demo code:

```
private sensorIdSubject = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  this.sensorIdSubject.pipe(
    mergeMap(sensorId => 
      interval(5000).pipe(switchMap(() => this.getSensorData(sensorId)))
  ).subscribe(sensorData => {
    // Every 5 second, each of the sensorIds that have been selected in UI will 
    // get sensor data and emit new value here in subscribe, because all of them
    // have been merged.
  })
}

public chooseSensor(sensorId) {
  this.sensorIdSubject.next(sensorId);
}
```

Does this fit? I will update my code according to your needs, just tell me in the comment section.

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for your great response! I just have to get relevent data from subscribe method, then I must update the related chart series. But, I wonder what happens a lot of subscriber attacks update the same chart. Is this operation is thread safe?

Comment: Also, can I subscribe to directly interval() ? In this state, I can update chart int the related subscribe method without I don't know which data is received instead of merged subscribe method.

Comment: And another requirements, I can delete any sensor at any time. Thus, I must unsubscribe of related sensor when required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rxjs [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

It combines all your observables into one which emits all the values, so you subscribe to the forkJoin emitted observable, you can add pipe operators to it etc

something like:

```
let sensors = forkJoin(observable1, observable2)

sensors.subscribe(
   sensorData => {
      // You receive an object with your observables data
   }
)
```

If you need to get a variable amount of observables which emits different values, you can use BehaviorSubject this way:

```
let sensors = new BehaviorSubject<Array<Observables<yourType>>([])

sensors.next([newArrayOfObservables])

sensors.subscribe(
    sensors$ => {
      sensor$.forEach(sensor => {
        sensor.subscribe( // Do your logic)
      }
    }
)
```

This way you can add/remove observables, since ForkJoin only emits values when observables completes it only emits values once.

Again remember to manage your unsubscriptions.

Comment: So, can I add a new observable to forkJoin at any time? For example, forkJoin acceps a observable list. I have start forkjoin with interval, then I've add new observable to observable list. In this state, data will be received for new observable in the forkjoin?

Comment: I think what you can do in this case is create a BehaviourSubject, and then emit a forkJoin observable each time you update your list of observables, this way you will subscribe always to the last list of observables, remember to manage your unsubscriptions to avoid memory leaks

Comment: But these observables are different than others. So, one observable result musn't wait other observable results

Comment: Thank you so much. I accept another answer for my requirements.